# How to fix this? I am not getting the subtitle text

Tags: flutter

[See in the categories below catalogues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02Ccm.png) I am not able to display the subtitle below my image

What I've done is pasted below. I want to view the caption for the image and the paths are already provided and stored in ImageLocation variable for image and ImageCaption variable for the subtitle text. Below is the full code for the page and the class HorizontalList has been called in main.dart

```
   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HorizontalList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 80.0,
      child:ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        children: <Widget>[
          Category(
            imageLocation: 'images/cats/tshirt.png',
            imageCaption: 'shirt',
          ),

          Category(
            imageLocation: 'images/cats/jeans.png',
            imageCaption: 'jeans',
          ),

          Category(
            imageLocation: 'images/cats/dress.png',
            imageCaption: 'dress',
          ),

          Category(
            imageLocation: 'images/cats/formal.png',
            imageCaption: 'formal',
          ),

          Category(
            imageLocation: 'images/cats/shoe.png',
            imageCaption: 'shoe',
          ),

          Category(
            imageLocation: 'images/cats/informal.png',
            imageCaption: 'informal',
          ),

          Category(
            imageLocation: 'images/cats/accessories.png',
            imageCaption: 'accessory',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Category extends StatelessWidget {
  final String imageLocation;
  final String imageCaption;

  Category({
    this.imageLocation,
    this.imageCaption
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: (){},
        child: Container(
          width: 100.0,
          child: new ListTile(
            title: Image.asset(
              imageLocation,
              width: 100.0,
              height: 80.0
            ),
            subtitle: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter, 
              child: Text(imageCaption, style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),)
            ),  
          ),
        ),  
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to remove the `height: 80.0,` because it is trimming your cards

so your code will be

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HorizontalList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child:ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        children: <Widget>[
          Category(
            imageLocation: 'images/cats/tshirt.png',
            imageCaption: 'shirt',
          ),

          Category(
            imageLocation: 'images/cats/jeans.png',
            imageCaption: 'jeans',
          ),

          Category(
            imageLocation: 'images/cats/dress.png',
            imageCaption: 'dress',
          ),

          Category(
            imageLocation: 'images/cats/formal.png',
            imageCaption: 'formal',
          ),

          Category(
            imageLocation: 'images/cats/shoe.png',
            imageCaption: 'shoe',
          ),

          Category(
            imageLocation: 'images/cats/informal.png',
            imageCaption: 'informal',
          ),

          Category(
            imageLocation: 'images/cats/accessories.png',
            imageCaption: 'accessory',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Category extends StatelessWidget {
  final String imageLocation;
  final String imageCaption;

  Category({
    this.imageLocation,
    this.imageCaption
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: (){},
        child: Container(
          width: 100.0,
          child: new ListTile(
            title: Image.asset(
              imageLocation,
              width: 100.0,
              height: 80.0
            ),
            subtitle: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter, 
              child: Text(imageCaption, style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),)
            ),  
          ),
        ),  
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Sir, would you mind checking my image by clicking in the link that is in very first start of my problem statement. The caption appears for first three images. but as I go on adding the catalogues, it disappears

Comment: Yes, it worked but not removing the height of the container that you gave in the code but decreasing the height of the images

Comment: Thank you very much for the help

Comment: If it worked for you than you should accept the answer to reward the hard work done by others to solve your problem. It will help them to grow. :)